# Trying to understand DB relationship approach between various tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, orm, foreign-keys

Need to know DB stucture accurate or not?
Lets say there's customers / products / product_events

Where each customers can have multiple products, but a product can not have more than one customer, also each products can have multiple events

So here's what I have for example

```
customers           products                            product_events
-----------     ------------------------------      ------------------------
id | name           id | customer_id | name             id | product_id | event_title
```

as I guess this is one => many relationship

but here can be large number of products and some of them or lets say many of them (products) might not be assigned to customers (in other word not sold to customers)

So to keep list of products and customer's products' list seprate is that a good
approach to have any intermediary table to define products' relationship to customer?

So how about this stucture

```
customers           products        customer_products                   
-----------     ---------------     ------------------------------      
id | name           id | name       id | customer_id | product_id   

product_events
---------------------
id | product_id | event_title
```

For most of usage of these structures would be fetch list of products events by particular customer

Answer (score 1):

Having a `customer_id` column in the `products` table would mean that only one customer could have a particular product - e.g., you and I could not both buy the same model laptop, which just doesn't sound right.

Having an intermediate `customer_products` table sounds like the right way to go.

Comment: But brother, main thing is same model of product can be sold to only one customer, products are unique with their model numbers in this example

Comment: @MuhammadNawazMemon in that case, can you clarify your concern about the original approach? If each product can belong to exactly one customer, it seems like the right way to go. Just use a `null` for an unsold product.

Comment: Right, this is what I have currently..

but I can't able to set foreign_key to customer_id in products table as it can be null.. because of product is unsold..

what to do in this case?

Comment: You most definitely **can** have a foreign key on a column containing `null`s. A foreign key means the column isn't allowed to have a **value** that doesn't exist in the column it references. `Null` is not a value - it's the lack thereof, and "empty value", if you will.

Answer (score 0):

By considering "Customer" and "PRODUCT" tables there are Many to Many relation ship between two table. therefore you need to create 3rd table to maintain relationship. that 3rd Table should include two Primary key of both relation tables and Other attributes that bone because of relationship. 
3rd table primary key should be combination of both key from relation tables.

Comment: In a many:many table, there is no need for an `id`.  See my [_tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).